# Activity Sharing

Tags: activities

We have Activity object with OWD as private .. Accounts & Contacts with OWD as public ... Now the question I have is if I create a task under Account/Contact will the created task inherit the OWD of Account/Contact and become public ??

If yes ... I have a situation here ... We have an custom object called property with OWD as private and some sharing rules attached to it... Now If I create an task under Account/Contact and in the related to filed I relate it to this custom object.... Does my task here will inherit the custom object's private OWD and sharing rules??

Thanks for you replies !!

Answer (score 0):

A Task with with an OWD of private would still show up on the related activity list of the Accounts & Contacts with public (read or read/write) OWD, but the detail page for the Task wouldn't be accessible to anyone except the Owner of the Task. As a rule of thumb, for any record, the most restrictive permissions would be expected to prevail.

Comment: You're welcome user3881916. Community etiquette is to help others by marking your question as solved through checking the answer that resolved your issue. If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can also upvote posts and answers.